# How setup location block to strip port from url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup nginx to reverse proxy to a port dynamically based on port found in path.

So `https://my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/58585/some/route` goes to `https://localhost:58585/some/route`

And `https://my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/59595/some/route` goes to 
`https://localhost:59595/some/route`

I can hard code the config like this

```
server {
  server_tokens off;
  server_name my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com;

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  location /58585 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:58585/;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /59595 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:59595/;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}

server {
  if ($host = my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com;

  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and reverse proxy like this

```
ssh -R 58585:localhost:58585 myuser@my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com
ssh -R 59595:localhost:59595 myuser@my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com
```

This works as expected; then I've tried to make this dynamic

So `https://my-nginx.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com/targetPort/some/route` goes to `https://localhost:$targetPort/some/route`

The best I can come up with is the following but this keeps failing and with a 502 bad gateway.

```
location ~ /([0-9]+) {
    set $targetPort $1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$targetPort/;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Can someone guide me with the correct way to do this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> - When location is specified using a regular expression, and also inside named locations.
>
>   In these cases, `proxy_pass` should be specified without a URI.

I think you can try to use `rewrite` here to specify an URI:

```
location ~ ^/(\d+) {
    set $targetPort $1;
    rewrite /\d+(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$targetPort;
    ...
}
```

Maybe this can be optimized for one regex matching instead of two:

```
location ~ ^/(\d+)(.*) {
    set $targetPort $1;
    set $newuri $2;
    rewrite . $newuri break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$targetPort;
    ...
}
```

But it needs to be tested, nginx behavior is unpredictable sometimes.

**Update**

This is definitely can be optimized to

```
location ~ ^/(?<targetPort>\d+)(?<newURI>.*) {
    rewrite . $newURI break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$targetPort;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Im afraid this didn't work - until i added back my original hard coded location blocks - but what is interesting is i added an additional header to the regex location block and that is coming back in the response (when i include the hardcoded uri) which implies its using the regex location block.

Comment: eg this version doesn't work https://gist.github.com/chrismoutray/8f8d9b26e49f64a39b88af31903fbfa9

Comment: eg2 this version does work but includes `X-debugmsg: REGEX_59595` in the response header https://gist.github.com/chrismoutray/f0dad42f90d7098c8e4d5880a6de51e2

Comment: perhaps something to do with the extra ssl config managed by Certbot is causing an issue